# Angular : remove a Leaflet polyline between 2 markers

Tags: angular, leaflet, polyline

While i am using `interval` to update data json coordinates , i have connection path" between the last and the first point crossed original path of data json .

[image]

So how can i remove the "connection path" between the last and the first point marker ?

Code :

```
export class MapTrackBeforPage implements OnInit {
    map: Map;
    poly:L.Polyline

    protected points: { lat: number, lng: number }[] = [];

    constructor(
        private http: HTTP,
       public zone : NgZone) {

    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.getmarker()
    }


    async getmarker() {

        this.zone.runTask(()=>{
            setInterval(()=>{
                this.http.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'', {}, {})
                .then(data => {
                                                           -------------Polyline path ---------
            for (let datas of JSON.parse(data.data)['trail']) {

            this.points.push({ lat: datas.lat, lng: datas.lng })

            let poly = new L.Polyline([this.points], { color: 'red', weight: 3}).addTo(this.map);


            }

             })
            },5000)
        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths works as you want, but in your data has a little problem. See my picture, i think you have the first point two time in your data. Simple remove the redundancy with a helper function.
[image]
And i find another problem, you has an interval function and you dont remove the old coordinates, and when you get the new coordinates these points makes the problem.